# Why Priestess change her mind in planting the bombs?

Tags: plot-explanation, priest

In Priest (2011), Priestess already planted a bomb on the rail tracks:

[image]

But she took a risk by planting the bomb on her own bike and drives through towards the train and jumps off.

[image]

Then it will hit the train and explode which will happen in the next shot.

Why did Priestess change her mind in planting the bombs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She planted the explosives but was forced to detonate them another way.

During her fight with the familiars on motorcycles **one of them destroyed the detonator for the explosives**, so another detonation method had to be employed, in this case, by impact with the train.